# jQuery 'click' event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't for the life of me figure out why this click function isn't working on this codepen. I know how to use jQuery's `click` method. If a second set of eyes could look at this and diagnose, it would much appreciated. Here is a fork of my codepen, the `click` method is up top and looks like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  alert('clicked!');
});
```

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<section class="left">
  <button class="left-button">Show Chart</button>
</section>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/warPjx) is the codepen.

(I've used the exact same `click` method [here](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/BNwmVV) and everything works fine)

Comment: `.chart-container` is above your button

Comment: Before you go z-index crazy and create a bigger headache for yourself, especially using negative values my god. See if you can restructure your HTML to not need to z-indexs on three different elements. I almost never use z-index anymore unless I really really have to. Without knowing the goal of your HTML it's hard to give advice, but we've isolated the problem, the fix isn't necessarily to change another z-index.

Comment: Alternatively, I just added `pointer-events: none` to the blocking element (`.chart-container`). This allows me to click through to the button without implementing z-index solutions.

Comment: Careful http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events Doesn't work on IE 10 and below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your CSS. I removed your CSS and it worked. Your buttons are blocked by stuff. They need to be in front to get clicked.

Your sections are set to z-index of -1.

Comment: Yes, it is hidden. after removing CSS style it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/ghrnvm16/).

Comment: I added `pointer-events: none` to the `.chart-container`, allowing me to click through to the button. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are hidden! under some element.

Answer (score 0):

give the button an id and run from console `$('#id').click()` to check if it´s really not working, and it is working, the click is not triggered because some css generates overlying elements that get clicket instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `<div class="chart-container">`. When you click on the button, actually the click is being made to the container.

You can solve it by adding `z-index:-5;` to your `.chart-container` CSS style.

Comment: See above comments, `pointer-events: none` fixed the problem, too.